# Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen'

Tags: truffle

Am receiving "Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen' " error from the this line of code.

```
emit AuctionCreated(msg.sender, auctionId);               
                   ^
```

when trying to deploy a contract through truffle.

any help ??

THANKS IN ADVANCE !

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. solidity compiler version in my framework is not compatible with emits, only compilers after `^0.4.19` works with `emit`.